# Application failed codesign verification

Tags: objective-c, xcode, upload

"Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)”

I get this error when trying to upload my app through the Application Loader.

Any ideas whats wrong and how I can sort it?

Adam

Comment: Searching inside SO as well as using google will supply a plethora of troubleshooting ideas - this is a common problem, you just have to figure out which solution belongs to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your configuration in this [iPhone development forum topic](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2256-application-failed-codesign-verification.html)

Comment: This is for iPhone apps. I think Adam is talking about Mac Apps which require use of two different certificates and no entitlements.plist

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error pop-up due to XCode 4.x incorrectly handling schemes whose names contain spaces