# iphone :Application failed codesign verification Warning during making AdHoc

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, certificate

```
*** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool
```

`Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)`

`test-requirement: failed to satisfy code requirement(s)
 - (null)`

I am using Xcode 4 and I am getting above warning while making adhoc and `I am not able to install adhoc in my device to test`
How can I fix this?What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey may be this link might help.

Please check all the steps of the accepted answer in this link.

[Application failed codesign verification.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957187/application-failed-codesign-verification)

Also you need to check whether the Device ID is entered correctly and ticked in the adHoc Provisioning profile.

I really hope this helps you.

Also this two may be worth referring

[Application failed codesign verification. What do I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892148/application-failed-codesign-verification-what-do-i-do)

[Application failed codesign verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661993/application-failed-codesign-verification)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an adHoc provisioning profile and that you are signing your project with it. Also as Parth Bhatt said the device you want to run it on needs to be added to the device list on the developer portal.